# the jquery runs multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, hover

Sorry for my english :/
I have a Jquery code that executes as many times as there is the div with class `newness`. Because `newness` is in one 'for'

When I move my mouse on a div, I make the code JQuery below: remove 1 on the counter and I place a hoverdiv on this div(newness), and I post a db data, however for each item I have, there has a div newness, so it remake the action for many times that there are Articles I would like the jquery do only once the code

I think the div have to be Unique like:

```
<div class="newness-<%=activity.id %>
```

but i can't do that in the JQuery :

```
$('.newness-<%=activity.id %>')
```

If there are two activities in my DB the code below will add run twice the `Post` method and twice `--num` (counter).

Here's the code:

```
<div class="newness" data-id='<%=activity.id %>'>NEW</div>
```

jQuery, I have tried hover, it's the same.

```
$('.newness').one('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).addClass('hover');
  var num = parseInt($.trim($('.body__activity_counter').html()));
  $('.body__activity_counter').html(--num);
  if (num == 0) {
    $('.body__activity_counter').addClass('hover');
  }
  newnessId = $(this).data('id');
  $.ajax({
    url: '/user_activities.json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      user_activity: {
        activity_id: newnessId
      }
    }
  })
})
```

If my mouse hovers this div and I have two activities, here are the logs:

> ```
>   UserActivity Create (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "user_activities" ("activity_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["activity_id", 4], ["user_id", 2], ["created_at", "2018-05-28 10:59:26.615344"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-28 10:59:26.615344"]]
>
> ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:11
>    (1.0ms)  COMMIT
>
> ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:11
>   UserActivity Create (8.6ms)  INSERT INTO "user_activities" ("activity_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["activity_id", 4], ["user_id", 2], ["created_at", "2018-05-28 10:59:26.617042"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-28 10:59:26.617042"]]
>
> ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:11
> ```

Comment: Where is the 'for' function you mentioned?

Comment: _“I don't know how to fix this”_ - and we don’t know how you’d even _want_ to fix it either. So please first of all describe what you actually _want_ to happen, instead of what is happening now. What is the desired end result you are going for here? A proper description of that is completely missing from your question. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for my english, 
I try to describe the situation more explicitly, is that better? @CBroe

Comment: Im not an expert in ruby on rails, but this happened to me with .NET MVC. I had this javascript code asociated to every partialView of the item, so the elements with this class were binded by multiple on change methods. If you load this code several times in your page th method will bind several times. I had to change it and add this code to the main page, so it doesn't load this code for each element generated.

Comment: `.one` still executes the handler at most once _for every single element_ in your collection. But this should be easily solvable if you _remove_ the event handler again from _all_ those elements, inside your handling of the _first_ event of this type that occurred …

Comment: do you have an example to illustrate this?

Comment: Thanks @AlbertoCh That was exactly That ! Thanks =)

Comment: No problem, I wasn`t sure if it was that, but when it happends to me was difficult to diagnose it. Glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing the place of the script because this component that was executed for many times that there were articles in my db

thanks @AlbertoCh